# Rails flash notice in current view, before redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to flash a message, in the "new" view when the user submits the form, but, **before the controller redirects to the "show" view.**

I run a .sh script from the create method upon the submission of the form. The script takes a couple of minutes to run. The form sits inside the "new" view. The form etc.. were all scaffolded so using standard conventions.

How can I flash a message in the "new" view, before the .sh script runs and the controller redirects?

new.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>New Job</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

jobs_controller:

```
  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)

    flash[:notice] = 'Job Started' #added notice here but it doesn't flash in the "new" view

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job finished' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    job_call = 'sh testScript.sh' #var for a test sh file to run 
    system(job_call) #add sh script here

  end
```

Comment: I just got it rigged up with some JS, but wondering if there is a better rails solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is clearly a workaround to the problem. But I achieved it with unhiding a div or just flashing a JS alert with the notice message on the form submit:

```
<%= f.submit 'Run Job', :onclick => "return showNotice()"%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The flash message isn't happening because that only happens when Rails sends a Response back to the client (the browser) and the browser renders a template.

The Response is only sent back once everything in the `create` method has finished. This is the crux of your problem.

The blocker is that in Rails you can only do one redirect or render per controller method, even if you try to cheat and call another method that contains the second render or redirect. You get a `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`.

I don't think there's a way round this and I don't think you could even achieve it with Rails AJAX. It looks like your Javascript solution is the only way. Why don't you post up your solution?

Comment: Yeah you're right.. I was hoping there is a workaround for the rendering with the notices :(